# How do I auto delete txt messages?

Tags: php

I was wondering if it's possible to auto delete messages after 30 minutes example

chat.txt

Without me opening and clear it all. How do I do it? Thanks !

Comment: you could write a script that executes as a cron job.

Comment: cron job, learn what cron jobs are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
//** path to file
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

//** check file age     
if (strtotime($file) > strtotime("-30 minutes")) {
  $fage = 'old';
  //** file is older -- do something
} else {
  $fage = 'new';
  //** file is NOT older -- do something else
}

//** print result
echo $fage;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need config "cron job" on your host...
1- you needed to linux commands for run corn jobs for php version:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-do-i-put-for-the-cron-job-command
2- set time for run jobs.for 30 minute and repeat too--set--> */30
3- create "cron.php" file...
 and type this codes..
file_put_contents("file.txt", "");